# Prove that these sets are countable :

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that these sets are countable :

A. Set of relations over natural which is composed by exactly one ordered pair.

B. Set of relations over natural composed by finite number of ordered pairs.

thanks.

Comment: I assume that the answer should rely on a bijection function from naturals to the sets, but don't know how to express it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set A is essentially the collection of all singletons from the set $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. (Can you see why?) So the question is: can you prove that $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable?

The second set is the collection of all *finite* subsets of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. Perhaps you can prove that that the set of all subsets of a given *finite* size is countable, and then take a union?

Comment: For the second set, can I prove that the set is countable relying on that |N^k| (k in N) =|N|?

Comment: @galeck: I would say that *if* you can prove that $\mathbb{N}^k$ is countable for any finite $k$, then you can rely on that fact. If you cannot prove it, then I would be wary of relying on it...